# Acoustic Guitar tuning key

Tags: acoustic-guitar, tuning, strings, key

My acoustic guitar's one of tuning keys gear teeth got broken while tuning (G string).Here's a image. What can I do t fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They're fairly standard, so you can order a whole machine head from ebay, etc. No need to take the old one off, if you're lucky. Just unscrew the crosshead screw, push the new cog on. There are generally two fittings: a star or a circle with two flat sides. Check before ordering, also count the teeth to ascertain the replacement has the same number. You *may* have to buy a complete set of six - I did the last time I mended a Gibson with 'snot' machine heads, but there's no need to change everything if you don't want to. That may involve screw holes in different places on the headstock.